# How is the relation between discreete 2d convolution and neural network convolution

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, neural-networks

I have a question about how to formalize the definition of neural network convolution.

When it is coded, we express the 2d convolution like (in the case of a 3x3 kernel)

$C [x,y] = \sum_u \sum_v A[x-1+u, y-1+v] \cdot B[u,v]$ [3](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53)

This is pretty similar to what I see in the [Multidiminetion discreet convoltuion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_discrete_convolution)

But in that case, it is defined as:

$q(j,n) = \sum_i \sum_m f(i,m) \cdot p(i-j, n-m)$
(from book: [Multidimentional digital signal processing, dudgeon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyLOE.png)

Do you know how what is the relation between these two formulations? They look similar, they should represent the same thing, but I understand only the first, not the second.